# Woocommerce: Product category page using the wrong template

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, store

I have a WooCommerce store set up and I need to have it so that the store front shows the categories and then clicking through lists the products in that category. I have changed the store url to /soft-sell (it's a brand thing) and got it looping through the categories. The url for the click through page is /soft-sell/joe-b (for example), but the click through page is using the 'page-home.php' template and I can't find anything about why this is happening or how to change it. All I'm seeing on the category page is the home page. Anyone have any ideas?

Further info: I have declared woocommerce support in my functions

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone finds this in the future, the solution is posted [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/212767/woocommerce-return-404-on-category-pages)

It's to do with the permalinks page having the incorrect custom structure, it needs to be /%product-category%/ not /%product_cat%/